# Noobslide: circular option

Tags: jquery, mootools, carousel

I try to play around with noobslide and encountered an problem.

I would like to implement the circular:true from mootools to work with my noobslide.

Anybody knows how to achieve that?

My Page:
http://wwww.kleinraum.at/?page_id=1190&themedemo=kleinraumv3

```
<script>
window.addEvent('domready',function(){
 var nS6 = new noobSlide({
    mode: 'vertical',
    box: $('idee_slider'),
    size: 220,
    autoPlay: true,
    circular: true,
    interval:1000,
    items:  $$('#post_idee_slide span'),
    addButtons: {
        previous: $('prev_idee'),
        play: $('play_idee'),
        stop: $('stop_idee'),
        next: $('next_idee')
    },

});
});
</script>
```

http://www.efectorelativo.net/laboratory/noobSlide/

Comment: Not familiar with the noobslider, what is the behaviour you don't have but want to have?

Comment: noobslide gets for the width the total number of items, multiplies it with "size", sets "top=0" and goes on to change per interval top=-220, -440, until it reaches the width-parameter, lets say 660.

Comment: then it goes back to 0. Since my version shows up to 3 pictures same time, the container always ends up half empty before juping back. I want it to go circular, like mootools http://mootools.net/forge/p/carousel since noobslide is an abbreviation of mootools i figured it possible?

Comment: the mootools carousel you pointed does not scroll back to start, it keeps on removing and appending new images. if you want it to "go around" maybe you could use caroussel instead?

Comment: Yeah, i already gave it a thought, gut i would have to restructure completely. I thought there is maybe an easier way.

Comment: check what gives more work. maybe the css/js adjustements to make the carousel fit would be the best way...

Comment: just did it. Works great!

Comment: great! if you post your steps here as a answer you get a +1 from me :)